# Mojo IDE - Generate For Loop Block in Verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga, mojo

So, I have been racking my brain on this issue with the latest version of Mojo-IDE v1.3.6

Below is a short snippet of my code. As you can see I am attempting to use a generate with a for loop to create many instances of the 'Hashers' Block.

```
genvar i;

generate
    for (i = 0; i < 64/LOOP; i = i + 1) begin : HASHERS
        wire [511:0] W;
        wire [255:0] state;

        if(i == 0)
            sha256_digester U (
                .clk(clk),
                .k(Ks[32*(63-cnt) +: 32]),
                .rx_w(feedback ? W : rx_input),
                .rx_state(feedback ? state : rx_state),
                .tx_w(W),
                .tx_state(state)
            );
        else
    sha256_digester U (
                .clk(clk),
                .k(Ks[32*(63-LOOP*i-cnt) +: 32]),
                .rx_w(feedback ? W : HASHERS[i-1].W),
                .rx_state(feedback ? state : HASHERS[i-1].state),
                .tx_w(W),  
                .tx_state(state)
            );
    end

endgenerate
```

However, I get the following error when i try to synthesize:

```
Line 89, Column 38 : extraneous input '.' expecting {')', '[', '<=', '*', '+', '-', '?', '&', '|', '^', '~^', '^~', '/', '%', '==', '!=', '===', '!==', '&&', '||', '**', '<', '>', '>=', '>>', '<<', '>>>', '<<<'}
Line 90, Column 46 : extraneous input '.' expecting {')', '[', '<=', '*', '+', '-', '?', '&', '|', '^', '~^', '^~', '/', '%', '==', '!=', '===', '!==', '&&', '||', '**', '<', '>', '>=', '>>', '<<', '>>>', '<<<'}
```

The errors are on lines

```
                .rx_w(feedback ? W : HASHERS[i-1].W),
                .rx_state(feedback ? state : HASHERS[i-1].state),
```

According to Verilog-2000 guidelines this should be a legal as I should be able to access previous index of 'HASHERS' to obtain the 'W' bits for rx_w.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards,
S

Comment: I think that it is a system verilog extension, not verilog `[cnt +: 32] `. It probably causes an issue on the next line for you.

Comment: Hey Serge - thanks for the comment. I commented out that line and the error persists. I wonder if mojo-ide uses verilog or system verilog.

Comment: the second guess is that `HASHERS[i-1].W` is not parsed correctly by your compiler. Try to add the name of your module to it: `yourmodule.HASHERS[i-1].W`

Comment: Just gave that a shot  - the module name is sha256_transform - i tried sha256_transform.HASHERS[i].W and unfortunatey the error sticks. HASHERS is instantiated as part of the for loop, so It is in the same module as the rest of the code.  I appreciate your help!    
Update: Using Hashers[0].W seemed to worked. I wonder if it has something to do with using genvar as an index for a block.

Comment: Just to be clear, `[cnt +: 32]` is Verilog (not just SystemVerilog).

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with vcs and it did not produce any issue with this code. So, it looks like your verilog compiler has issues with generate blocks.

I suggest to move your `W` and `state` declarations outside the block as the following:

```
 wire [511:0]  W[64/LOOP-1:0];
 wire [255:0]  state[64/LOOP-1:0];
 genvar i;
 generate
    for (i = 0; i < 64/LOOP; i = i + 1) begin : HASHERS

       if(i == 0)
         sha256_digester U (
                            .clk(clk),
                            .k(Ks[32*(63-cnt) +: 32]),
                            .rx_w(feedback ? W[I] : rx_input),
                            .rx_state(feedback ? state[i] : rx_state),
                            .tx_w(W[i]),
                            .tx_state(state[i])
                            );
       else
         sha256_digester U (
                            .clk(clk),
                            .k(Ks[32*(63-LOOP*i-cnt) +: 32]),
                            .rx_w(feedback ? W[i] : W[i-1]),
                            .rx_state(feedback ? state[i] : state[i-1]),
                            .tx_w(W[i]),  
                            .tx_state(state[i])
                            );
    end

 endgenerate
```

Comment: Okay, sounds like an issue with Mojo-IDE, then. I'll try that when I get back to my computer.. witll that create a separate wire for each HASHER?  So that if I refer to HASHER[X].W[Y] it would be different than HASHER[Z].W[S]?

Comment: Yes, nothing really changes. There will be one instance `U` per loop, as before. There will be **no** HASHER[whatever].W. there will be just **W[i]** inside your module. it is not a pa part of the HASHER block any longer.

Comment: I see. Later on in the code I need to parse  State and W. so for example if i want to grab the first 32 bits of x for a given  the call would be state[x][31:0]?  sorry for all the questions, I really do appreciate all the help you have provided so far.

Comment: yes, you would use it as 2-dimensional array in your comment.

Comment: Well, it will compile, so that's good - off to testing. thanks again for your help , Serge.